# Google chrome session expire=null not working

Tags: javascript, session, node.js, google-chrome, express

According to [connects documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) the session should expire when the browser is closed:

> By default `cookie.maxAge` is `null`, meaning no "expires" parameter is set
>   so the cookie becomes a browser-session cookie. When the user closes the 
>   browser the cookie (and session) will be removed.

I am using express 3 with [connect-mysql](https://github.com/nathan-lafreniere/connect-mysql) for session store (Tried with connect-mongo too and its the same), and this is how i set the session data.

```
 req.session.userid = results[0].id;
 req.session.ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
 req.session.useragent = req.headers['user-agent'];
 req.session.is_logged_in = true;
```

This all works fine except in google chrome browser for some reason (This is in OS X Lion.I have no possibility to test under win or linux right now).

Anyone had this problem in google chrome and know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly wild guess, but I wouldn't be too surprised if it's this. Google chrome will keep running in the background if you have any extensions that make use of this installed. If that's the case after a log off-log in the session should be reset.

If that isn't it, could you please open the developer tools (`cmd+alt+i`) and copy all the information about the cookie from there (`resources`->`cookies`->`yourdomain.com`). (Especially what's written in the `Expires` column, because it should say `Session`)

Comment: Well now it suddenly works. Removed all extensions, reinstalled chrome. And now it works as expected. But is there a way to prevent this if a user got extensions installed? Because this messed up the sessions. New sessions where added as a user logged in and out etc. Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Comment: Try installing the extensions one by one and maybe you will find a specific extension which was messing with your cookies in that case, as *normal* extensions shouldn't ever cause this.

Comment: I will do that. And post the results here when i find out wich one caused the problems. Thanks